# Passing boolean value in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

This is a simple question but I want to pass a boolean value for a field in a JSON string that will be interpreted by Rails as boolean, e.g., what do I use for "a" below? Is it 0 or 1 or "true" or "false" or ?

```
{ 
  "a": ??,
  "b": [1,2,3...],
  "c": 3
}
```

Is there another way to test for true or false in Ruby besides comparing it to true, e.g.,

```
a = params[:a]
if a == true
```

Comment: i thought there would be some sort of pre-made module already available to parse JSON. Most languages have this built in by now or at least have a third party solution that is free and reliable.

Comment: Yes, there is a module to parse JSON, ActiveSupport::JSON, that's not an issue but what it does to treat a JSON value as boolean is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott M is right on the JSON part. On the Rails end, I need to use this method to convert it into Rails boolean format

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(params[:a])

Answer (score 5):

in JSON the value for true is.... `true`

edit:

a quick google search turned up [this solution](http://flori.github.com/json/) over on github. This will save you the trouble of making a JSON parser yourself, assuming that is your end goal.